# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode14

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

got error after update Xcode version 14.3

here is error screenshot:-
[image]

need to solve it...   [image: Xcode version]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this steps :

1. go into this file Open the file Pods/Targets Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-framework
2. if you can't find this file just search in xcode with this text source="$(readlink "${source}")" you will get this file
3. Search source="$(readlink "${source}")" into file
4. Replace source="$(readlink "${source}")" to source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

Hope this will help you! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the pod folder then reinstall the pod file with the command `pod install`.
Also, make sure your pod file is updated. Use the command `pod update`.

Comment: not working, still getting error..